# KNN Error for Flights Dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, random, machine-learning

I am trying to learn how to do KNN in R, and am practicing on the flights dataset from the package nycflights13. I get an error running the below code saying

> 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

My code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(class)


deparr <- na.omit(flights[c(4, 7, 16)])

classframe <- deparr[3]

flights %>% ggvis(~dep_time, ~arr_time, fill = ~distance) %>% layer_points()

set.seed(1234)

ind <- sample(2, nrow(deparr), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))

flights.training <- deparr[ind==1, 1:2]
flights.test <- deparr[ind==2, 1:2]
flights.trainlabels <- deparr[ind==1, 3]
flights.testlabels <- deparr[ind==2, 3]

predictions <- knn(train = flights.training, test = flights.test, cl = flights.trainlabels[,1], k = 3)
```

Comment: Do you understand why you are doing the things that you're doing? you have two different data frames. Try `> str(flights.training)`
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 219806 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dep_time: int  517 533 542 544 554 555 557 557 558 558 ...
 $ arr_time: int  830 850 923 1004 740 913 709 838 753 853 ...
`> str(flights.test)`
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 108257 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dep_time: int  554 558 558 559 608 613 615 627 629 629 ...
 $ arr_time: int  812 849 923 702 807 925 1039 1018 824 721 ...

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Unfortunately I am still as confused as I was before. I'm sorry I'm a bit slow with this stuff.

Comment: I should mention that classframe is never used. I used it before but then changed things around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that divides up the train and test sets based on percentages. If you want to split out the two subsets in a different way, you should be able to work from this, but it proves that it works.

```
deparr <- na.omit(flights[c(4, 7, 16)])
set.seed(1234)

# prepare to divide up the full dataset into two groups, 65%/35%
n <- nrow(deparr)
train_n <- round(0.65 * n)

# randomize our data 
deparr <- deparr[sample(n)]

# split up the actual data. We will use these as inputs to knn
flights.train <- deparr[1:train_n, ]
flights.test <- deparr[(train_n + 1):n, ]

# target variable, $distance, is in column 3, so exclude from train and test
predictions <- knn(train = flights.train[, 1:2], test = flights.test[, 1:2], cl = flights.train$distance, k = 10)
```

This runs and I get as a result:

```
> str(predictions)
Factor w/ 209 levels "80","94","96",..: 121 159 18 54 207 18 94 55 159 136 ...
```